# Update column based on other column values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that stores clients that are then grouped under one client who are considered the 'Head' of the group. So a client is considered a 'Head' if they appear in the 'Group' column, even though they may not be in their own 'Group'. The table may appear as follows:

```
+--------+-------+------+
| Client | Group | Head |
+--------+-------+------+
| ABC    | ABC   | Yes  |
| DEF    | ABC   | No   |
| GHI    | GHI   | Yes  |
| JKL    | MNO   | Yes  |
| MNO    | PQR   | Yes  |
| PQR    | MNO   | No   |
| STU    | STU   | Yes  |
+--------+-------+------+
```

Here we can see that 'Head' records for client JKL and PQR are incorrect. What I need is a list of just the clients whose 'Head' column is incorrect and what it should be (Yes/1 or No/0). What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by Head column is incorrect?

Comment: JKL has 'Head' listed as 'Yes', but isn't actually listed as a 'Group' for any other client. If a client isn't a 'Group' then it can't be a 'Head'. PQR has 'Head' set to No, but is listed as the 'Group' for client MNO so should be set as Yes for 'Head'.

Comment: Your explanations are unclear. Are you saying, a client is a a head if and only if it is listed as a Group for any client? Find a way to finish "A client is a head if and only if ...". Then edit your clear defintion into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @a Table (Client Varchar(10),[Group] Varchar(10),Head Varchar(3))

Insert into @a Values ('ABC','ABC','YES') 
Insert into @a Values ('DEF','ABC','No')
Insert into @a Values ('GHI','GHI','YES')
Insert into @a Values ('JKL','MNO','YES')
Insert into @a Values ('MNO','PQR','YES')
Insert into @a Values ('PQR','MNO','No')
Insert into @a Values ('STU','STU','YES')

-- uncomment here to get only wrong ones
--Select * from (

Select a.*, Coalesce(h.RealHead,'No') as RealHead 
       , CASE WHEN Coalesce(h.RealHead,'No')<>a.Head then 'ERROR' else 'OK' end as Info
FROM @a a
LEFT JOIN (Select Distinct [Group], 'YES' as RealHead from @a) h 
ON h.[GROUP]=a.Client -- Join real Heads with clients

-- uncomment here to get only wrong ones
--) s where Info='ERROR'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL select statement WHERE and double equal sign ==

```
select * from tableName where Head=="No";
```

You can update the records to what you like
   ;

```
UPDATE tableName
SET Head = 0
WHERE Head="No";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(Client varchar(50), [Group]  varchar(50), Head  varchar(50))

insert into @t values( 'ABC','ABC','Yes'),
('DEF','ABC','No'),
('GHI','GHI','Yes'),
('JKL','MNO','Yes'),
('MNO','PQR','Yes'),
('PQR','MNO','No'),
('STU','STU','Yes')

select * from @t t1 
where t1.client not in (select distinct [Group] from @t t3 where t3.Head = 'Yes' and t3.Client = t3.[group]) 
--and Head = 'Yes' --please uncomment this line and check the result, if any issue to desire your result, tell me
```